# concat in reduce not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I'm trying to use `Array.reduce()` to turn a string that looks like this:

`'React, {PureComponent, Fragment}'`

into an array like this:

`['React', 'PureComponent', 'Fragment']`

To do this I'm using a recursive `Array.reduce()` like this:

```js
const str = 'React, {PureComponent, Fragment}';

const moduleFinder = (acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.charAt(0) === '{') {
        const insideStr = curr.substring(curr.indexOf("{")+1, curr.indexOf("}"));
        const insideModules = insideStr.split(',').map(e => e.trim());
        return acc.concat(insideModules.reduce(moduleFinder, []));
    } else {
        acc.push(curr);
        return acc;
    }
}


console.log(str.split(',').map(e => e.trim()).reduce(moduleFinder, []));
```

However, I keep getting `Maximum call stack exceeded`!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you don't care about nesting, why not use a regex: `let results = str.match(/[a-z]+/gi);`?

Answer (score 6):

I feel like you might be doing too much here. This simple function should do what you want:

```js
let str = 'React, {PureComponent, Fragment}';

function replaceAndSplit(str) {
    return  str.replace(/{|}/g, '').split(',').map(e => e.trim());
}
console.log(replaceAndSplit(str));
```

Comment: Nice answer, also consider trimming the results: `str.split(',').map(e => e.trim());` Also no need to store the results back to `str`, just return them directly: `return str.split(',')...;`

Comment: Fraekin beautiful

Comment: Thanks! I always feel like I'm "supposed" to use functional methods like `map, reduce, etc` but I guess sometimes its better to just go with the simpler solution.

Comment: I don't think the OP is doing too much. Seems like they're writing a recursive parser. If nesting isn't possible, then yes.

Comment: Crazy Train if we are going to be creating an array from object destructuring on nested properties we would have to know the desired format of the array with some items nested deeply.